# What unit of measurement does the Solr geodist() function return?

Tags: solr, geospatial

I have been using solr's geodist() function to return the distance between two points, however the data that returns is always less than 1. I just want to know what unit of measurement does the geodist() method return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit of measurement depends on the schema configuration (schema.xml) of the field your using the function on. The solr docu says for the RPT (SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType) :

> distanceUnits
>
> This is used to specify the units for distance measurements used
>   throughout the use of this field. This can be degrees, kilometers or
>   miles. It is applied to nearly all distance measurements involving the
>   field: maxDistErr, distErr, d, geodist and the score when score is
>   distance, area, or area2d. However, it doesn’t affect distances
>   embedded in WKT strings, (e.g., BUFFER(POINT(200 10),0.2)), which are
>   still in degrees.
>
> distanceUnits defaults to either kilometers if geo is true, or degrees
>   if geo is false.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/spatial-search.html#schema-configuration-for-rpt